# ControllerAdvice does not work with actuator/health

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an Interceptor to log the request of each HTTP request:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RequestBodyInterceptor extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {

@Autowired
LoggingService logService;

@Autowired
HttpServletRequest request;

@Override
public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    logService.displayReq(request,body);
    return super.afterBodyRead(body, inputMessage, parameter, targetType, converterType);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    return true;
}
```

}

To configure which package can intercept, I added the `basePackages` attribute to `@ControllerAdvice` annotation with a value which I got from properties file:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"${log.logged-packages}"})
```

When I put the package of my controllers it's work and I didn't see logs for the actuator/health endpoint :

```
log.logged-packages=com.my.package
```

But when I change the value to a list or just put the `org.springframework` package, I can't see any log of actuator calls :

```
log.logged-packages=org.springframework.boot.actuate
```

Or

```
log.logged-packages=org.springframework.boot.actuate, com.my.package
```

Any ideas, please?